# Make a list of root with os.walk

Tags: python, os.walk

I am trying to setup a specific folder/file structure, which I will then copy into my test setup. I want a list of unique folders, that I can then create.

**How to I get root into a list?**

If I do the following:

```
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(path):
    print root
```

I get:

```
/Users/Me/Folder
/Users/Me/Folder/SubFolder
```

But as I want use it in a for-loop it gets messed up.

```
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(path):
    for x in root:
        print x
```

and I get this result:

```
/
U
s
e
r
s
/
M
e
/
F
o
l
.
.
. and so on
```

Comment: Don't add `[Solved]` to qour question title. Wait a moment, then you can accept your own answer

Comment: If you are only just learning Python, my strong recommendation would be to target Python 3.  You should only learn Python 2 if you need to maintain old software (and even then only if you are convinced it isn't cheaper to simply port it to Py3).

Answer (score 2):

To get an variable you are iterating over into a list simply append it to a list:

```
list = []
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(path):
    list.append(root)
```

To create a list of folders you can simple use `os.mkdir(path)`:

```
for path in list:
    os.mkdir(path)
```

if you want an additional print statement to see which folders you created use:

```
for path in list:
    os.mkdir(path)
    print("created:{}".format(path))
```

Comment: Maybe also show the OP how to just `print(root)` inside the loop.

Comment: Why didn't I think of appending...? `print(root)` doesn't turn root into a list.

Answer (score -1):

Finally I found the answer:

```
for root, dirs, filenames in os.walk(src_path):
    for x in root.splitlines():
        print x
```

Comment: That's not useful. `root` is already the path you are looking at, you don't need to loop over it.

Comment: `root` is only a single line, so `root.splitlines()` returns only one thing, which is `[root]`.
You could replace the entire inner for loop just by `print root` and it would do the exact same thing.

Comment: Actually it is a line per dir, so I get 4 lines on the command above. `root` has the full path and `dirs` only the name of the directory.